# No request information sent with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, timeout, asihttprequest

I am experiencing an issue on iOS 4.3+ with ASIHTTPRequest where a request is fired but no data (Request methed, url, headers, etc) reaches the server. The connection times out because it never hears back.

The server hears the empty request (after some delay), then hears a valid request which is of course never reported to higher level code because the connection has timed out. This is all kind of strange because the request was not configured to resend data.

Often this happens after the app has been pushed to the background for some time (15 min or more) and the phone has been allowed to sleep.

My configuration of the request is as follows:

```
NSMutableData *postData = nil;

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[self baseURL],requestPath];

OTSHTTPRequest *request = [OTSHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:45];
//Set up body
NSString *queryString = [self _RPcreateQueryString:query];
if ([queryString length]>0) {
    if(method == RPAsyncServerMethodPost || method == RPAsyncServerMethodPut){
        postData = [[[queryString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES] mutableCopy] autorelease];
    }else{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAppendingFormat:@"?%@",queryString]];
        [request setURL:url];
        if (!url) return nil; //url String malformed.
    }
}

// ... ///
// method setting stripped for brevity

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

if(headers){
    for (NSString* head in headers) {
        if ([[headers valueForKey:head] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) 
            [request addRequestHeader:head value:[headers valueForKey:head]];
    }
}
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Length" value:postLength];
[request setPostBody:postData];
```

OTSHTTPRequest is simply a subclass of ASIHTTPRequest that contains properties for a string tag, a pretty description, and other bling for use by consuming objects and does not override any ASI stuff.

Can anyone shed a light on why/how ASI could open a connection and then send absolutely nothing for minutes at a time?

Edit: Just to clarify. The connections DO make contact with the server, it just never sends any data through the connection from what my server logs can tell. This seems to always happen on app wake and effects all connections including NSURLConnections spawned by MapKit. the whole app just seems to loose its marbles.
I also see a bunch of background tasks ending badly right before this, but i can never catch them while in the debugger.

Comment: The above is the code for the constructor method to create the request. I do call startAsynchronous after all this, and it does get called each time.

Comment: new info: before an episode of these null requests i see a series of the following on app wake in the system log: "<Warning>: Can't endBackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 17, or it may have already been ended." im not starting background tasks, so i assume this is a symptom of what evers going wrong. Could these background execution requests be ASI?

Comment: you still need to post code how you call startAsynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt want to say anything till a few days passed with out the issue. The solution in this case was very obscure.

It appears the version of TestFlight i was using has a bug in it that may have contributed to this issue. Since its removal i have not experienced the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are starting your request based on the code that you have provided.  Try call the -[startSynchronous] or -[startAsynchronous] methods of your OTSHTTPRequest object after you are done setting its various properties.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is the code for the constructor method to create the request. i do call startAsynchronous after all this. i'll add a note to my original.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the delegate, either I overlooked it or you stripped it out.

Comment: i am setting the delegate right before i send the request. and the delegate gets called for the timeout and all works as expected. (as far as doing the right thing with the error)